# I am not able to see "Connect" option in Production in Docusign.com, while it is available in Demo/Sand box account

Tags: docusignapi

I am not able to see "Connect" option in Production in Docusign.com, while it is available in Demo/Sandbox account[Production DocuSign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p35eH.png) [Sandbox DocuSign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpm0F.png)

How should I configure connect/webhook in Prod?

Answer (score 3):

Are you logged in as an account administrator?

The Connect feature is not included with all DocuSign pricing plans.

If you want to use Connect to create account-level notification subscriptions then your account needs the "Connect" feature enabled.

If you want to create per-envelope notification subscriptions via the API, that feature is available with every account. You should be able to view/manage the resulting notifications via the Connect panel on the Administration tool.

Answer (score 3):

I have to ask DocuSign support to enable the Connect option and they did. Thus it got fixed